# sorting elements by attribute on a simple nested structure

Tags: xslt

I'm still struggling to get my head around a lot of XSLT but have a specific question.

I have a simple nested structure that I want to sort by an attribute (name).

The file has a single root node and then a series of nested nodes. I need to have all the nodes under root sorted within the level they are. The hierarchy is nested to an unspecified level.

The input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <node name="A">
    <node name="C"/>
    <node name="B"/>
  </node>
  <node name="F"/>
  <node name="E"/>
</root>
```

Needs to be transformed into:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <node name="A">
    <node name="B"/>
    <node name="C"/>
  </node>
  <node name="E"/>
  <node name="F"/>
</root>
```

I won't bore you with my feable attempts at solving this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do wish the elements to stay within the level they are currently in, firstly, you would need a template to match any element

```
<xsl:template match="*">
```

Then you would use **xsl:copy** to copy the element, and **xsl:copy-of** to copy any attributes

```
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
     ... more code here...
  </xsl:copy>
```

And within the **xsl:copy** you would then use **xsl:apply-templates** to process the child elements, along with **xsl:sort** to select the order

```
     <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
        <xsl:sort select="@name" />
     </xsl:apply-templates>
```

Put this altogether gives you this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
            <xsl:sort select="@name" />
         </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your input XML the following is output

```
<root>
  <node name="A">
    <node name="B"/>
    <node name="C"/>
  </node>
  <node name="E"/>
  <node name="F"/>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is similar to Tim C's, but is just using an identity transform with an `xsl:sort`. This way you don't loose comments or processing instructions if they're present.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
                <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```